# inserting CLLocation latitude from coordinate into NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, cllocation

I'm doing something stupid, but not sure what. Here's my code:

```
NSMutableArray *latitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSMutableArray *locationArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CLLocation *location in self.allPins) {
    Location *locationObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    locationObject.timestamp = location.timestamp;
    locationObject.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
    locationObject.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
    [locationArray addObject:locationObject];
    [latitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: location.coordinate.latitude]];
    NSLog(@"here is the array for latitudes count: %d", latitudes.count);
    NSLog(@"here is the value for first latitude: %d", latitudes[0]);
}
```

`self.allPins` holds all locations received from `CLLocationManager`. Once a user is done moving and wants to save, I run the snippet above to both load the trajectory into a CoreData class to save on the user's phone and also into arrays to upload the data online. I'd like to have an array of latitudes longitudes, etc, but this isn't working out. While I can insert the information into my CoreData object just fine, I can't seem to simply extract the doubles/floats (tried it both ways but I thought it shouldn't make a difference?) out of the CLLocation coordinate. When I run the following code, I get a count for the latitudes array, but I get nonsense for the value:

```
2015-05-26 15:25:22.934 MileRun[665:196255] here is the value for first latitude: 426649664
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing the value of the NSNumber, but what I believe is the address of the NSNumber (somebody might correct me here if that is not was `426649664` is in his log).

Change `NSLog(@"here is the value for first latitude: %d", latitudes[0]);` to

<strike>NSLog(@"here is the value for first latitude: %f", latitudes[0].floatValue);</strike>

```
NSLog(@"here is the value for first latitude: %@", latitudes[0]);
```

**MORE INFO EDIT:**
The format specifier `%d` is for integers. You could print out the NSNumber with the format specifier for objects, which is `%@`. This would allow you to log with `NSLog(@"number = %@", latitudes[0])` and get the value for the NSNumber that way.

Also, when in doubt, set a breakpoint in your code and inspect the objects in the array with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that will not even compile (I just tried). For one thing the objects in the latitudes array don't have a floatValue property.

Comment: Every NSNumber has a `floatValue` property (which is what you are storing in `latitudes`). See my edit for another way to print the value by using the `%@` escape character in `NSLog`.

Comment: Minor nitpick on terminology. The `%@` is a format specifier, not an escape character. A backslash is an example of an escape character when used in a string literal.